# AES Encryption in Golang and Decryption in Java

Tags: java, scala, encryption, go, aes

I have the following AES Encryption function written in Golang.

```
func encrypt(key []byte, text string) string {
    plaintext := []byte(text)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)

    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
}
```

I am struggling to understand the flow to decrypt the generated text using Java. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Here is the Scala code, Not sure what's the problem with it.

```
def decode(input:String) = {
    val keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex("someKey".toCharArray)
    val inputWithoutPadding = input.substring(0,input.size - 2)
    val inputArr:Seq[Byte] = Hex.decodeHex(inputWithoutPadding.toCharArray)

    val skSpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
    val iv = new IvParameterSpec(inputArr.slice(0,16).toArray)
    val dataToDecrypt = inputArr.slice(16,inputArr.size)

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skSpec, iv)
    cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt.toArray)
}
```

Comment: Reproduced your code here: https://glot.io/snippets/een965dgb3 but still haven't gotten a java solution working

Comment: Where is the Java code? Note that CFB mode is used in streaming context: `XORKeyStream`.

Comment: @Ripul Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Java decoder (see also [online runnable demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/6iT), open and click "Execute"):

```java
String decode(String base64Text, byte[] key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    byte[] inputArr = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(base64Text);
    SecretKeySpec skSpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
    int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(inputArr, blockSize));
    byte[] dataToDecrypt = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArr, blockSize, inputArr.length);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skSpec, iv);
    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt);
    return new String(result, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Kevin in comments has offered [this demo](https://glot.io/snippets/een965dgb3) of the original Go encoder, where we can see the result of:

```
encrypt([]byte("0123456789abcdef"), "test text 123")
```

is `c1bpFhxn74yzHQs-vgLcW6E5yL8zJfgceEQgYl0=`.

Let's see how the Java decoder above deals with that input:

```java
String text = "c1bpFhxn74yzHQs-vgLcW6E5yL8zJfgceEQgYl0=";
byte[] key = "0123456789abcdef".getBytes();
System.out.println(decode(text, key));
```

Prints `test text 123` ✔

---

Scala version ([online runnable demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/6j6)):

```scala
def decode(input:String, key:String) = {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding")
    val blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize()
    val keyBytes = key.getBytes()
    val inputArr = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(input)
    val skSpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
    val iv = new IvParameterSpec(inputArr.slice(0, blockSize).toArray)
    val dataToDecrypt = inputArr.slice(blockSize, inputArr.size)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skSpec, iv)
    new String(cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt.toArray))
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    print(decode("c1bpFhxn74yzHQs-vgLcW6E5yL8zJfgceEQgYl0=", "0123456789abcdef"));
}
```

I think the only error in the Scala version is using `Hex.decodeHex`. You need a Base64 decoder that uses the URL-safe alphabet as described in RFC 4648, which `java.util.Base64` offers (since Java 8) with its `getUrlDecoder()`.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hugues Very useful, can you submit the encryption code of java? I mean encrypt from java and decrypt on golang? thanks.